# Mobilefirst 8.0 add java class file and access through adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am following [**Link**](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/mobileblog/entry/ibm_worklight_adapter_accessing_an_image?lang=en).

In this I have to add class files and apache commons files also. I can add this in Mobilefirst 7.1. How to add these files in 8.0. As all we have to use command lines and also no server folder in project folder structure of 8.0.

Like below screenshot I can add Encoder.java file in server folder of 7.1 project.

[image]

So how this can be done in 8.0 project. I am very new to 8.0 so any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Adapters in MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 are standard Maven projects.
In Maven you can reference either remote or local dependencies in the project's pom.xml file.

Read more about dependencies:

- In the MobileFirst Foundation developer center: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/creating-adapters/#dependencies
- In the Maven documentation: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

To add Java classes, simply put these in the src folder and as in standard Java pratice, import them.